# Laravel Sub-Domain Routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

When im try access my.domain.com, the DefaultController function will be executed, but the AccountController function should be executed.

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'DefaultController@getIndex'
]);


Route::group(['domain' => 'my.domain.com'], function(){

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

        Route::get('/', [
            'as' => 'account.home',
            'uses' => 'AccountController@getIndex'
        ]);

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() {


        Route::get('/login', [
            'as' => 'auth.login',
            'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'
        ]);

    });
});
```

Comment: Try moving the DefaultController stuff to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your catch-all route is catching the request before it has a chance to get into the subdomain routing.  Move the `DefaultController` portion to the bottom of the file.